# std::map and private constructor

Tags: c++

Here's a code that doesn't compile:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class A;

class B {
        friend class A;
        int b;
        B():b(1){};
        B(int b_):b(b_){};
};

class A {
        map<int,B> objects;
public:
        void init(){
              objects[2]=B(3);
        }
};

int main(){
        A a;
        a.init();
        return 0;
}
```

From what I understand in the error message:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h: In instantiation of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = int; _Tp = B; _Compare = std::less<int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, B> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = B; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = int]’:
foo.cc:18:24:   required from here
foo.cc:9:10: error: ‘B::B()’ is private
          B():b(1){};
          ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/map:61:0,
                 from foo.cc:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:469:59: error: within this context
           __i = insert(__i, value_type(__k, mapped_type()));
                                                           ^
```

the problem is "map" is not a friend of `B`, so it may not use constructor `B()` (incidentally I notice that `objects[2]=B(3);` requires `B()`!).

I found the following workaround:

```
objects.insert(pair<int,B>(2,B(3)));
```

which works... until `~B()` is also private.

So, is there a way to build a map of `B` inside `A` when `B`'s constructors and destructors are private?

Additional question: why is `objects[2]=B(3);` using `B()`?

Comment: _"So, is there a way to build a map of B inside A when B's constructors and destructors are private?"_ No.

Comment: "*From what I understand in the error message*" What error message?

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question in my opinion.  Maybe the wording is what upset peolpe?  Or maybe the absence of the compiler error you mentioned.  I upvoted it.

Comment: @Curious: thanks. What could be wrong in the wording?

Comment: `insert` only works because you call move constructor. Make it private ant it will break.

Comment: I think what upsets people is that the asker is trying to solve a problem that does not exist. Why make object unconstructable and then try to construct it? I think he wants a private member class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly speaking, it is not an answer to your question, but I think it solves your problem in a more elegant way.

Instead of making all the fields of B private and then messing with friend keyword in A, you might hide class B from outside world, by making it a private [member class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types):

```
#include <map>

class A {
    class B {
        int b;

       public:
        B() : b(1){};
        B(int b_) : b(b_){};
        ~B() {}
    };
    std::map<int, B> objects;

   public:
    void init() {
        auto b = B();
        objects[2] = B(3);
        objects.insert(std::pair<int, B>(2, B(3)));
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    A::B b; // 'A::B': cannot access private class declared in class 'A'
    a.init();
    return 0;
}
```

This way you still cannot construct B freely outside of the A, but A can use it in any way. This also unlocks finer granularity of encapsulation in B: some parts can be made private/protected from A. It is not the case with friend class code.

Schematically, you can think of your code as:

```
 A [ B [ private(a), private(b), private(c), ... ] ]
```

While my code is more like:

```
 A[ private(B[a, b, c]) ]
```

i.e. privateness is "factored out" of B

Comment: That's exactly what I need! I wasn't aware of private member classes. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator[]/ , it says

> A call to this function is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> (*((this->insert(make_pair(k,mapped_type()))).first)).second
> ```

The default constructor is being called from within the class `std::map`'s scope, which is not a friend of this class.  Therefore the error.

The error should be there.  Such a constructor should not be declared private then.

Another way to go about solving this issue is to delegate construction of the objects to the class `A`, and have a map of integers to pointers (or reference wrappers) to B.  This map should then only be accessible through an interface that `A` exposes.  That way the entire lifetime of the `B` objects is managed by `A` and no invariants are broken.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was not discussing the relevance of the error, just not understanding why and looking for a solution :-)

Comment: @L.Levrel I should have posted a solution I thought was decent!  I was preoccupied with other things and didn't think about it.  I'll edit my answer

Comment: It was decent. The Lisp-like citation (so many parentheses!) forced me to carefully examine what operator[] does. So it was helpful. I accepted Drop's answer which solves my problem, although it doesn't answer the question, strictly speaking: please forgive this to me, as a beginner I didn't express my question very well. Thanks for taking the time to edit your already-upvoted answer, since I can't upvote it twice, I'll upvote your comment: a small step towards your 2,000 rep! (they do give rep for upvoted comments, right?)

Comment: @L.Levrel Thank you!  I am not really sure when SO gives rep for upvoted comments but I did not get any rep this sadly.  If you want to give me rep then http://stackoverflow.com/users/5501675/curious any upvotes would be lovely!

Comment: Welcome to 'Space Odyssey' reputation :-)