# How to disable creating/copying obj outside a Factory-Method?

Tags: c++, factory, factory-pattern, move-constructor, emplace

I have a class, that has very heavy payload, so that it is very expensive to create/copy/move an instance of this class.
Since they will not change after the app has finished initialization, there is no need to create temporary objects of this class anywere. I only need to cache objects in a container(`std::map`), and offer a "const reference" when needed.

The thing that must be emphasized is that I'm seeking a solution which can avoid double-create or unnecessary copy a object before add it into the container(I don't think a solution likes one @getsoubl proposed can resolve the problem, because it does not eliminate doulbe-creating or unnecessary copying).

So I want to arrange the constructor method into "private/protected" section of the class body, so as to forbid any of creating/copying/moving outside of the "Factory-Method". Following is my original solution:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   // methods of the class
   static const MyClass & findObject( int iKey ) {
      auto pair = mapObjects.try_emplace( iKey, iKey );
      if ( pair.second )
         cout << "New object has been created" << endl;

      return pair.first->second;
   };

   // deleted
   MyClass() = delete;
   MyClass( MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass( MyClass && ) = delete;
   MyClass( const MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass( const MyClass && ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( MyClass && ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( const MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( const MyClass && ) = delete;

private:
   // vars of the class
   static map<int, MyClass> mapObjects;

   // vars of instance
   string some_heavy_payload;

   // methods of instance
   MyClass( int iKey ) : 
     some_heavy_payload( std::to_string( iKey ) ) {};
};

map<int, MyClass> MyClass::mapObjects;

int main() {
   const MyClass & obj = MyClass::findObject( 1 );
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

But I'm put into a contradiction that the "std::try-emplace" can NOT also call the constructor of MyClass.
The compiler reports: "error: ‘MyClass::MyClass(int)’ is private within this context".

So I tried the solution 2:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   // methods of the class
   static const MyClass & findObject( int iKey ) {
      if ( mapObjects.find( iKey ) == mapObjects.cend() )
         mapObjects[iKey] = MyClass( iKey );

      return mapObjects[iKey];
   };

   // deleted
   MyClass() = delete;
   MyClass( MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass( MyClass && ) = delete;
   MyClass( const MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass( const MyClass && ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( const MyClass & ) = delete;
   MyClass & operator=( const MyClass && ) = delete;

private:
   // vars of the class
   static map<int, MyClass> mapObjects;

   // vars of instance
   string some_heavy_payload;

   // methods of instance
   MyClass( int iKey ) {
      some_heavy_payload = std::to_string( iKey );
   };
   MyClass & operator=( MyClass && src ) {
      some_heavy_payload = std::move( src.some_heavy_payload );
      return *this;
   };
};

map<int, MyClass> MyClass::mapObjects;

int main() {
   const MyClass & obj = MyClass::findObject( 1 );

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
};
```

This time I got a error: "use of deleted function ‘MyClass::MyClass()’".
I guess that is resulted by "[]" operator of std::map, because it tries to call the default constructor of MyClass.

How can I get it done?

Comment: This topic seems to be duplicate
Please have a look in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37184137/stdmap-and-private-constructor

Comment: I don't think my question is duplicated with that, because the solution I'm seeking includes not only "how to put a obj into container", but also "how to avoid unnecessary copying".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to lock creation down, simply pass a key to everyone allowed in!

```
class MyClass {
    class Key {
        Key() = default;
        friend class MyClass;
    };
    MyClass(MyClass const&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const&) = delete;
    static map<int, MyClass> mapObjects;
public:
    static MyClass const& findObject(int iKey) {
        auto [iter, created] = mapObjects.try_emplace(iKey, Key(), iKey );
        if (created)
            std::cout << "New object has been created\n";
        return iter->second;
    };

    MyClass(Key, int iKey)
    : some_heavy_payload(std::to_string(iKey))
    {}
private:
    string some_heavy_payload;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a map of pointers (which are cheap to copy or move into the map), rather than a map of objects, and if you use a map of smart pointers then you can still have the map manage the lifetime of the objects within it.

Here is some proof-of-concept code which should let you take the idea forward.  In practise, `createA` and the map would be hidden away inside some factory function to to populate the map.

Note that `A`s constructor is private and that we cannot copy a `unique_ptr`, only move it.  Also, `make_unique` is off-limits because `A` has a private constructor, but that's no big deal, cost-wise.  Copying pointers is cheap.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    A () { std::cout << "Create A" << '\n'; }
    A (const A &) = delete;
    A &operator= (const A&) = delete;
    A (A &&) = delete;
    A &operator= (const A&&) = delete;
public:
    ~A () { std::cout << "Destroy A" << '\n'; }
    friend void createA (int key);
};    

static std::map <int, std::unique_ptr <A>> objects;

void createA (int key)
{
    std::unique_ptr <A> a (new A);
    objects.insert (std::pair <int, std::unique_ptr <A>> (key, std::move (a)));
}

int main ()
{
    createA (1);
    createA (2);
}
```

Output (showing object lifetime management by the map):

```
Create A
Create A
Destroy A
Destroy A
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v6VkiNl0zaHqYd9u)

---

**Alternatively**, write an efficient move constructor (which is not usually difficult) and move your objects into your map rather than copying them, like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

class A
{
    A () { std::cout << "Create A" << '\n'; }
    A (const A &) = delete;
    A &operator= (const A&) = delete;
    A &operator= (const A&&) = delete;
public:
    A (const A &&) { std::cout << "Move A" << '\n'; }
    ~A () { std::cout << "Destroy A" << '\n'; }
    friend void createA (int key);
};    

static std::map <int, A> objects;

void createA (int key)
{
    A a;
    objects.insert (std::pair <int, A> (key, std::move (a)));
}

int main ()
{
    createA (1);
    createA (2);
}
```

Output:

```
Create A
Move A
Move A
Destroy A
Destroy A
Create A
Move A
Move A
Destroy A
Destroy A
Destroy A
Destroy A
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/v6VkiNl0zaHqYd9u)

Comment: That still allows others to make their own, and doesn't eliminate all copies and moves.

Comment: @Deduplicator I don't think you read my post very carefully.  Outsiders can't make their own `A`s because `A`s constructor is private and `createA` is hidden inside some factory code somewhere and not exposed in any header file.  Perhaps I should have declared it `static`.  I believe I covered efficiency concerns in my post.  If one can write a cheap `move` constructor for class `A` then fine, go that route.  If not, use the `unique_ptr` approach.  Sure, a few _unique_ptrs_ are moved around but so what?  That costs peanuts.  The objects they own are neither moved nor copied.

Comment: As I can get at the map, and thus an instance, I can do: `auto x = existing_a;`. There are other approaches without that loophole.

Comment: @Deduplicator The map is hidden away in the same file as `createA`.  I have clarified this, and deleted the offending constructors and assignment operators.

Comment: Ok, the first alternative, only handing out pointers and doing the creation yourself works, though adds indirection. Truthfully, I meant the second one, and there the only option seems to be not exposing any `A` to anyone at all.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, I prefer the first one.  I rather regret adding the second.  Is there any indirection cost in converting a `unique_ptr` to a `const ref` (that's what the OP wants to return from a lookup)?  If there is, it will be swamped by looking up the key in the map in any case.

Comment: By means of unique_ptr doing is my current method in the product code, but I don't like it. I carp the way de-refering a smart-ptr would spend time, especially while the seeking will be executed very frequently.

Comment: Personally, I think the cost is trivial, but you have to admit that Deduplicator's solutions is very neat.